# Method chaining on list with condition

Tags: c#, .net

```
var someList = otherList.ReplaceAll(foo, bar);

if (someCondition)
{
    someList = someList.ReplaceAll(someOtherFoo, someOtherBar);
}
```

In my code, I am having the above code snippet, I find the `if` statement very annoying and would like to do something like this instead:

```
var someList = otherList
    .ReplaceAll(foo, bar)
    .Given(someCondition)
    .ReplaceAll(someOtherFoo, someOtherBar);
```

such that `ReplaceAll(someOtherFoo, someOtherBar)` is only executed when `someCondition` is `true`.

Is that possible?

Comment: There are no LINQ operators in this question. Just method chaining, using your own methods or some third-party library. What does `ReplaceAll` do and what does it have to do with LINQ?

Comment: What you propose is only possible if the `.Given` method sets or resets some kind of flag on the List + returns the List, and then `.ReplaceAll` "magically" knows about that flag and understands that it should do nothing if the flag is or isn't set. If this is all about the standard `List<T>`, then the bad news it that it contains is no such flag that could be set.

Comment: if you want this without the flag on the enumerated object you can have an ambient context that holds this info for you... not saying that that will produce easy/good code or that it comes without a price... but if sticking with the standard List<T> is the problem...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess I should rephrase my question, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can indeed create an extension as suggested by others, I wouldn't do that in actual production code because it's defeats the purpose of Linq.

Linq is functional and good for processing sequences or streams. Each Linq chaining operator processes incoming data and transforms it to another data. `Given` extension you are looking for is procedural and doesn't do anything with the sequence.

`Given` also doesn't support lazy evaluation which is one of the features of Linq.

By introducing such extension you just making the code harder to read for the next person working on this code.

By contrast, good old `if` can be easily understood by everyone.

If you want to save couple of lines you can use ternary operator:

```
var someList = otherList.ReplaceAll(foo, bar);
someList = someCondition ? someList.ReplaceAll(someOtherFoo, someOtherBar) : someList;
```

Comment: I would definitely use simple _if_ statement. if (condition) someList = someList.ReplaceAll(....);

Comment: Thanks for the advice, although it doesn't strictly answer my question!

Comment: @Noobnewbier thanks! Sometimes the best answer to "how can I do X" is "you don't need it, use Y instead". C# certainly allows to write code like `count.While(condition, i => i += 1)` but that's just weird way to say `while(condition()) { count += 1; }`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create an extension?

```
    public static List<T> ExecuteIf<T>(
        this List<T> list, 
        Func<bool> condition, 
        Func<List<T>, List<T>> action)
    {
        return condition() ? action(list) : list;
    }
```

```
var someList = otherList
    .ReplaceAll(foo, bar)
    .ExecuteIf(() => someCondition, (l) => l.ReplaceAll(someOtherFoo, someOtherBar));
```

Answer (score 1):

To use fluent method chaining with such a conditional operation, you could create a **`ReplaceAllIf`** extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<T> ReplaceAllIf<T>(this List<T> list, bool condition, T valueToFind, T replacement)
    {
        return condition ? list.ReplaceAll(valueToFind, replacement) : list;
    }

    public static List<T> ReplaceAll<T>(this List<T> list, T valueToFind, T replacement)
    {
        return list.Select(x => x.Equals(valueToFind) ? replacement : x).ToList();
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var list = new List<string>{"a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d"};

var result = list
    .ReplaceAll("a", "XXXX")
    .ReplaceAllIf(true, "c", "YYYY")
    .ReplaceAllIf(false, "d", "ZZZZ");
```

Working demo -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/gknS4z

Comment: I am trying to look for a more generic solution to this if possible. the method you suggest will work for this specific use case, but if I want to do something else I would need to write a different method for them as well.

Answer (score 1):

what you are describing is called a fluent interface

the linq functions are extension functions with a signature like

```
IEnumerable<T> someFunction<T>(this IEnumerable<T>, ...)
```

as you see it's an ordinary function that returns something ...

fluent interfaces make use of this by returning something that is implementing an interface for enumeration in this case, but also using the return type to change the set of functions you can call on the result ...

here is an example program...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SoFluentExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var en = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));

            var result = en
                            .ReplaceAll(1, 100)
                            .Given(true)
                            .ReplaceAll(2, 200)
                            .Given(false)
                            .ReplaceAll(3,300)
                            .ToArray();
        }
    }

    public class MyFluentEnumerableWithCondition<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> en { get; private set; }
        public bool condition { get; private set; }

        public MyFluentEnumerableWithCondition(IEnumerable<T> en, bool condition)
        {
            this.en = en;
            this.condition = condition;
        }
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return en.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return en.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
    public class MyFluentReplacerEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T> 
    {
        private IEnumerable<T> en;
        private T foo;
        private T bar;
        public MyFluentReplacerEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> en, T foo, T bar)
        {
            this.en = en;
            this.foo = foo;
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new MyEnumerator(en.GetEnumerator(), foo, bar);
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        private class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
        {
            private IEnumerator<T> en;
            private T foo;
            private T bar;
            public MyEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> enumerator,T foo, T bar)
            {
                this.en = enumerator;
                this.foo = foo;
                this.bar = bar;
            }
            public T Current => replace(en.Current,foo,bar);

            private T replace(T current, T foo, T bar)
            {
                return current.Equals(foo) ? bar : current;
            }

            object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

            public bool MoveNext()
            {
                return en.MoveNext();
            }

            public void Reset()
            {
                en.Reset();
            }

            #region IDisposable Support
            private bool disposedValue = false; 

            protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (!disposedValue)
                {
                    if (disposing)
                    {
                        en.Dispose();
                    }
                    disposedValue = true;
                }
            }
            public void Dispose()
            {
                Dispose(true);
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
    public static class MyExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> en,T foo, T bar)
        {
            return new MyFluentReplacerEnumerable<T>(en, foo, bar);
        }

        public static MyFluentEnumerableWithCondition<T> ReplaceAll<T>(this MyFluentEnumerableWithCondition<T> en, T foo, T bar)
        {
            if (!en.condition)
                return en;
            return new MyFluentEnumerableWithCondition<T>(en.en.ReplaceAll(foo,bar),true);
        }
        public static MyFluentEnumerableWithCondition<T> Given<T>(this IEnumerable<T> en, bool condition)
        {
            return new MyFluentEnumerableWithCondition<T>(en, condition);
        }
    }

}
```

`ReplaceAll` is defined for `IEnumerable<T>` and `MyFluentEnumerableWithCondition<T>`
the type decides which implementation is called, and even though `MyFluentEnumerableWithCondition<T>` is implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, the more specific signature is used